# x:key keyword in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Sometimes it seems that the **Name** and **x:Name** attributes are interchangeable. We can refer both **Name** and **x:Name** of a Framework element in XAML. But in case of **x:key**, WPF not providing **"key"** keyword like **Name**. Both **Name** and **x:Name** are for same purpose. **Name** would be available without typing **x:**. Why we are not able to use **key** like this in XAML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually a [`Name` property on `FrameworkElemnet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx).  The [`x:Name` Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) actually will map to the `Name` property because of a [`RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.runtimenamepropertyattribute.aspx) that causes the parser to perform the mapping.  These are actually not 100% interchangable - it's more  of a one-way mapping, where the parser sets the `FrameworkElement.Name` property to match the value specified in `x:Name`.

No such property or attribute exists for "Key", so the `x:Key` directive can't map through to a property in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about Xaml then there is only the x:Name. WPF framework can map one of its properties to XAML's x:Name by using the `RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute` on the class which assign one of property to  `x:Name` of Xaml. So setting `x:Name` is equivalent to setting `Name`.

`x:Key` is on the other hand is `Xaml` key to the resource. It is used to uniquely identify the resource in the `ResourceDictionary`.